# Android application to send many files (> 25MiB) at once as attachments in Gmail

Tags: android, gmail

I'm looking for a Android application that can

- send send many files (> 25MiB) at once as attachments in Gmail. My user story: I have 100 compressed pictures. Each of them is 2 MB. I would like to send via email everything at once as attachments (no hosting on Gdrive or somewhere else). Basically pictures will have to be sent in several emails. To put it otherwise, I'm asking for a way to automatically send multiple email messages to send all the files. Ideally not one email per file, but each email should contain as many pictures as possible based on a maximum that I would specify.

Free if possible.

Edit: More on my motivation. The issue with cloud storage is that I don't want to have those files filling up my cloud account (I want to avoid asking the recipient to tell me when he's done, and all unlimited private cloud storage I'm aware of turn out to be crap), or have to deal with expiring links, and I don't want anyone but the recipient to be able to access it

Comment: Recipient mailboxes can become full prior to them connecting a client and downloading the files. By avoiding cloud storage you open up this kind of problem - no smart client can work around limitations on the destination like that (you would need to monitor and re-send, plus possibly apologise to your recipient for blocking up their inbox so that other emails were lost)

Comment: @NeilSlater I know that most recipients have enough storage. I can check by their domain space (Gmail: 7 GB, Yahoo: 1TB, etc). If their inbox is full I should receive an error message.

Answer (score 1):

Zip up the photos then upload them to Google Docs/Google drive. Google Drive is designed to solve the issue around 25 MB file limitations of mail. E-mail one link to the photos on Google Drive and all the photos can be downloaded specifically by whom you want to share them with.

If you have certain groups of photos, for certain people then zip them up separately, upload each zip file to Google Drive, then Share the download link to the individuals whom you want to have access to the files.

If you want the photos to be available just for limited time, ask the sendee to confirm they have downloaded their photos. Then Remove the Share access, or Delete them from your Google Drive after they've replied.

I'm not sure why you have concerns about using Google drive, you're willing to send the photos via Gmail, but don't want to share them via Google Docs? In both cases the photos are hosted by Google.

Comment: Thanks, I've added more details in my question to explain why I don't want to use cloud storage.

Comment: For an extra layer of security, you could password protect the zip file before uploading it to Google Docs. The password would only be known be the recipient.